# Drag and drop in collectionView with data

Tags: arrays, swift, collectionview

I'm trying to add drag and drop to my collectionView, and I have some issues;

When I drag my cell, the data disappear (UITextField). I think I don't save the data in my dataArray correctly...

And the second issue: the drag and drop "works" (without data lol) in the collectionView where I create the cell, but I can't drag this cell to another collection view. The animation is play, but I can't perform a drop.

this I my code:

fist, my class Task, my dataArray is of this type:

```
class Task: NSObject, Codable, NSItemProviderReading, NSItemProviderWriting {

var task: String?
var button: Bool?

init(task: String, button: Bool) {
    self.task = task
    self.button = button
}

static var writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
    return [(kUTTypeData) as String]
}


func loadData(withTypeIdentifier typeIdentifier: String, forItemProviderCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) -> Progress? {

    let progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 100)

    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        let data = try encoder.encode(self)
        let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        progress.completedUnitCount = 100
        completionHandler(data, nil)
    } catch {

        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }

    return progress
}

static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
    return [(kUTTypeData) as String]
}

static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> Self {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let myJSON = try decoder.decode(Task.self, from: data)
        return myJSON as! Self
    } catch {
        fatalError("Err")
    }
}
```

Here I try to save my data and perform drag and drop:

```
extension LTHM_Todo: UICollectionViewDataSource {


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.myText.text = dataArray[indexPath.row].task
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 300, height: 40)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArray.count
}

private func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    return cell
    
}


extension LTHM_Todo: UICollectionViewDragDelegate, UICollectionViewDropDelegate {  
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal
{
    if session.localDragSession != nil
    {
        if collectionView.hasActiveDrag
        {
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        }
        else
        {
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden)
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator)
{
    let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
    if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath
    {
        destinationIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    else
    {
        let section = collectionView.numberOfSections - 1
        let row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
        destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
    }
    
    switch coordinator.proposal.operation
    {
    case .move:
        reorderItem(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
        break
        
    default:
        return
    }
}

fileprivate func reorderItem(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView) {
    let items = coordinator.items
    if items.count == 1, let item = items.first, let sourceIndexPath = item.sourceIndexPath
    {
        var dIndexPath = destinationIndexPath
        if dIndexPath.row >= collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        {
            dIndexPath.row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1
        }
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.dataArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
            self.dataArray.insert(item.dragItem.localObject as! Task, at: dIndexPath.row)
            collectionView.deleteItems(at: [sourceIndexPath])
            collectionView.insertItems(at: [dIndexPath])
        })
        coordinator.drop(item.dragItem, toItemAt: dIndexPath)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let item = self.dataArray[indexPath.row]
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: item)
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
    dragItem.localObject = item
    return [dragItem]
}
```